# How do you find out what RPMs in a repository depend on a particular RPM?

Tags: dependencies, rpm

It's easy to check what packages a single RPM depends on, but how do I do the opposite, and find out what RPMs depend on a particular RPM?  Is there an easier way to do it than searching through all the other RPMs' dependency lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New Answer:**

There are a some scripts out there:

http://maisondubonheur.com/rpm-analyzer/ appears to work for RHEL
http://noisybox.net/computers/debdeps/ has one for Debian's dpkg

**Old Answer:**

*This is for capabilities, not modules*

```
rpm -q --whatrequires capability
```

See http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-query-parts.html

Answer (score 2):

For recent versions of yum-utils, just use:

repoquery --tree-whatrequires <package>

...there are a bunch more options, in very recent yum-utils, if you want the output to be something else.

If you need to run it on older versions (like RHEL-5), you can use:

http://james.fedorapeople.org/yum/commands/pkg-deps-tree-view.py

Edit, sorry you wanted:

http://skvidal.fedorapeople.org/misc/pkg-provs-tree-view.py

...which is whatrequires, the deps-tree-view is requires.

Answer (score 0):

Another kludgy way I tried is to try and remove a package as non-root (so remove will fail and you won't accidentally remove the package).

You will get a list of dependant packages, e.g. as non-root:

```
rpm -e zlib
error: Failed dependencies:
        libz.so.1()(64bit) is needed by (installed) boost-iostreams-1.57.0-4.fc17.x86_64
        libz.so.1()(64bit) is needed by (installed) rpm-build-libs-4.12.0.1-13.fc17.x86_64
        libz.so.1()(64bit) is needed by (installed) java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1:1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc17.x86_64
.......... 317 more lines ........
```

Comment: I'm unsure if this is the best answer but it surely is creative.